# sort json content in terraform file

Tags: sort, filetype-json

I'm trying to sort following json that is inside of terraform file. I'd like to sort it alphabetically by `"name"` value (ENV->PORT->USERNAME):

```
      {
        "name": "PORT",
        "value": sometimes_there_is_no_quotation_mark
      },
      {
        "name": "ENV",
        "value": "${var.env}"
      },
      {
        "name": "USERNAME",
        "value": "${var.username}"
      }
```

I've been trying `jq` `json.tool` and [`SortGroup`](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/76m6xa/sorting_multi_line_objects/) function but unfortunately none of them works for me.

Comment: Since you have `jq` there's no reason to use Vim to address your issue. If you're a Unix/Linux user you can ask about `jq` at [the associated site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Otherwise [SuperUser](https://superuser.com), I suppose.

Comment: I'd prefer some some nice vim module, or sleek way of sorting this out in vim ... That's why I've asked here.

Comment: You can look [this screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vZmJa0Xi1Q) which shows you how you can achieve what you want with macros and such.